# Ошибка при запуске *.exe - Точка входа не найдена

Tags: c++, qt, dll, mingw, exe

При запуске *.exe получаю ошибку: [image: Ошибка]

Все файлы .dll я закинул в папку, которые он просил и тут это!
Что делать с этой проблемой?

Comment: Формулировка вызывает подозрение на ручной процесс закидывания. Лучше использовать windeployqt.exe из комплекта сборки. Основной же вопрос: из QtCreator запускается?

Comment: @EvgenyShmidt естественно в QtCreator запускается. Проблема в том, что когда запускаю windeployqt.exe открывается консоль и сразу же закрывается. Пробовал от имени админа запустит - тоже не работает((

Comment: Такие вопросы появляются на ru.so постоянно, продублирую сюда свой комментарий из аналогичного вопроса, заданного недавно - "Ошибка "точка входа не найдена" говорит о том, что в папке лежит не та dll. Самая распространенная ошибка - положить библиотеки из папки с креатором вместо собственно Qt"

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Спасибо! Если хотите, напишите это ответом на вопрос, а я зачту его как решением =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка "точка входа в процедуру не найдена в библиотеке" в приложениях Qt вызвана тем, что в папку положены неправильные dll, самая распространенная ошибка - положить dll из папки с QtCreator вместо dll из папки со сборкой Qt. Нужно добавлять те библиотеки, которые лежат в `%QtDir%/%QtVersion%/%QtBuild%/bin`, в моем случае, например, это `C:\Qt\5.11.1\mingw53_32\bin`

Также для нормальной работы приложения нужно положить файл

`%QtBuild%/plugins/platforms/qwindows.dll` в папку `./platforms` с exe файлом

и для Qt 5.10 и новее

`%QtBuild%/plugins/styles/qwindowsvistastyle.dll` в папку `./styles`  с exe файлом

В качестве автоматизированного решения можно воспользоваться утилитой windeployqt, но по моему опыту она тащит много лишнего мусора, который не нужен для работы программы